# Encoding a group of images with ffmpeg or mencoder

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a group of H.264 images (I-frames only) that I want to encode into JPEG with a single command. For a single image encoding, I can use the following (ffmpeg):

```
ffmpeg -i raw_image image.jpg
```

It works fine. What about a list of images? I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
ffmpeg -i raw_image%d image%d.jpg
```

I need a solution either in ffmpeg or mencoder. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion):

> For creating a video from many images:
>
> ```
>  ffmpeg -f image2 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -r 12 -s WxH foo.avi
> ```
>
> The syntax `"foo-%03d.jpeg"` specifies to use a decimal number composed
>   of three digits padded with zeroes to express the sequence number. It
>   is the same syntax supported by the C `printf` function, but only
>   formats accepting a normal integer are suitable.